# Как проиграть OGG файл внутри программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нашёл способ проигрывать файл через библиотеку os:

```
import os
os.startfile ("имяфайла.ogg")
```

Но в таком случае он открывает установленный на компьютере VLC плеер и открывает файл через него. Как сделать так, чтобы не открывалось никаких дополнительных программ на компьютере, а просто запускался звуковой файл?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772830/how-do-you-play-ogg-files-in-python-in-linux